# How to encrypt in AES using CryptoJS with key size of 128?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

I have searched and found examples of AES with the default 256 key size and find it worked already. But when I want to use 128 key size, there is little information.

I have extracted code from the aes test from CryptoJS:

```
        var C = CryptoJS;

        var plainText = '00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff';
        var key = '000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f';

        var encryptedText = C.AES.encrypt(C.enc.Hex.parse(plainText), C.enc.Hex.parse(key), { mode: C.mode.ECB, padding: C.pad.NoPadding }).ciphertext.toString();

        console.log(encryptedText);

        var decryptedText = C.AES.decrypt(C.lib.CipherParams.create({ ciphertext: C.enc.Hex.parse(encryptedText) }), C.enc.Hex.parse(key), { mode: C.mode.ECB, padding: C.pad.NoPadding }).toString();

        console.log(decryptedText);
```

This worked, but if I want to use a different plain text like 'Hello World' then it failed. Also what if I want to use a password like 'my-key-001'? As I have read that CryptoJS expect to use 256 key size if I pass a password.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: "As I have read that CryptoJS expect to use 256 key size if I pass a password." So? What's the problem with that? Other than the key size and a slight increase in the number of rounds, AES-256 has the same properties as AES-128.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This worked, but if I want to use a different plain text like 'Hello World' then it failed.

You have used the `noPadding` and that is the issue. The example is multiple of 16-byte that causes no problem, however your next plaintext is not. You can use `noPadding` if

1. your message is an exact multiple of the block size, though still not recommended.
2. you want to pad the message yourself, probably that is you want to test a new padding scheme that we don't see in your code.

You should you padding like

```
padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
```

> As I have read that CryptoJS expect to use 256 key size if I pass a password.

CryptoJS supports AES-128, AES-192, and AES-256. According to your key size it will select the key variants. If you use a password it will generate a 256-bit size. That is %40 times slower than AES-128 since it requires 14 rounds. However use a good password, see below.

> Also what if I want to use a password like 'my-key-001'?

A password with high entropy is important otherwise the attackers can be successful by testing passwords. The key generation cannot increase entropy. Therefore you need a good way to generate high entropy passwords like using [diceware](https://www.eff.org/dice).

> How to encrypt in AES using CryptoJS with key size of 128?

Just provide a 128-bit key.

> Does AES-128 has 128-bit security

Any block cipher, not only AES, has vulnerable to multi-target attacks. In that case it is not providing 128-bit security. Therefore you should use 192 or 256-bit keys. 
For a more detailed see this question [Has AES-128 been fully broken?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76738/18298)

> mode: C.mode.ECB

The ECB mode of operations is not advised, it is insecure and it leaks pattern. You should use modern encryption modes like AES-GCM which provides you not confidentiality but also, integrity and authentication.

While using GCM mode, make sure that you never use the same IV/nonce again under the same key. AES-GCM uses CTR mode for encryption and under the same key if the IV/nonce repeated then crig-dragging is possible. Also, it can leak the authentication key.